# When an electron achieves a velocity q, does the electron lose it's velocity at the expense of creating magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electrons

When an electron achieves a velocity $q$ by a force $F$ , does electron lose it's velocity at the expense of creating magnetic field? And what is the theory of electron moving without magnetic field with a velocity less than $q$. If some one explains it, I will be very happy with that. please........

Answer (score 2):

An electron in an inertial frame, and your "achieves a velocity q " presumably means it is a steady velocity q once reached, does not lose energy if it is not interacting with something.

It is true that it has a charge, moving with velocity q, and one can [calculate a magnetic field](https://www.pdx.edu/nanogroup/sites/www.pdx.edu.nanogroup/files/lecture_9_Magnetic_Fields_produced_by_a_current_ph_222_PRINT_9.pdf) that follows its path. It expends no energy as it is moving with constant velocity q to maintain its electric or magnetic field. These two depend on the inertial frame where they are measured as they are connected in Maxwell's equations.

In the inertial frame where the electron is not moving, i.e. its center of mass system, there is no magnetic field. The [E and B fields are connected](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/em/el4.pdf) through the equations by Lorentz transformations, and will have varying values dependent on the inertial frame of observation.

No a non accelerating moving electron does not lose any energy in supporting the E and B fields on its path. It is only with accelerations and interactions in general that energy can be added or subtracted from a moving charge in a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

If the electron was a small sphere of electric charge, then yes, creating magnetic field takes some energy and this has to come from somewhere, either energy of the agent pushing with force, or internal energy of the sphere. In the former case, the force will not accelerate as efficiently as if the sphere was not charged.

If the electron is a point charge, the usual Poynting expressions are not valid. In Frenkelian theory$^{*}$, there is no necessity to assign any energy to its magnetic field (because there is no self-interaction), so no energy has to be got from anywhere and the electron will accelerate just the same as uncharged material point of same mass.

- J. Frenkel, Zur Elektrodynamik punktförmiger Elektronen, Zeits. f. Phys., 32, (1925), p. 518-534. http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01331692

Comment: But magnetic field have some energy per unit volume. Where does is come from

Answer (score 1):

The kinetic energy of a charged particle resides largely in the magnetic field that surrounds the particle. There is no lag between the particle reaching a given velocity and the emergence of the magnetic field around the particle. By accelerating the particle, you're building up the magnetic field.  As long as the particle is not interacting with anything else, it will continue on its path with undiminished speed and with no change in its magnetic field (other than the fact that the magnetic field travels with the particle).

Note that the magnetic field due to the particle's motion relative to an observer results directly from the fact that the electric field (at the observer's position, and due to the particle's charge) changes continuously as the particle moves in relation to the observer.  Maxwell's equations describe how a changing electric field gives rise to a magnetic field.  In other words, the changing electric field experienced by the observer as the particle moves past results in a magnetic field also experienced by the observer.